# Calculation clouding hosting costs

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting

I'm looking for a good article/resource about calculating the costs of a clouding system hosting, ideas?

I just want to read other people experiences and avoid errors on my own...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a service that calculates the cloud hosting prices from multiple providers - [**cloudorado.com**](http://www.cloudorado.com/) . It is not an article but should be helpful in the context you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Every provider is a little different, but in general you can count on paying for:

- CPU hours
- RAM hours
- Disk storage hours
- In/Out bandwidth

Of these, the only one that can be difficult to estimate is bandwidth. It is - in most cases - also the least expensive so try to pick large enough figures that you won't be surprised. Also keep in mind that most providers do not charge for CPU and RAM while the instance is turned off, but many **do** charge at least some nominal fee for storage regardless. This is because even though the instance isn't running, the data must continue to be persisted and backed up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really informative sheet from a have-it-your-way PaaS
http://www.standingcloud.com/upgrades

Comment: quite descriptive, Cameron. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

A really informative and comprehensive video tutorial on how to calculate your application cost you can watch here: [How to Check your App Cost](http://jelastic.com/pricing)

Observing and controlling the charged costs by yourself is easy.
Besides, you do not pay for the dynamic resources when your environment is in stopped mode.